# RequireJS + Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I'm trying to use Bootstrap after loading it by RequireJS. Tried almost everything but still getting: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`

config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        underscore: 'vendor/lodash',
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min',
        text: 'vendor/plugins/text',
        bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {deps : ['jquery'], exports: '$'}
    }

});

require([
    'app',
    'bootstrap'
], function(App){
    App.initialize();
});
```

file that is supposed to use modal()

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    //...
    'bootstrap'
], function($, _, //...
    ){
    //.......
renderPlaceForm: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#place-modal').modal('show');
    }
//.....
```

I also tried omitting the "exports", loading bootstrap in App is also one of my tries. What is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Check if it will work with jQuery(...).modal. your jQuery may be in compatability mode, also check if jQuery and bootstrap are not included twice.

Comment: Still the same. How can I check if it is loaded once or twice?
I've just noticed in Network tab in DevTools that bootstrap is above jquery.

Comment: try removing bootstrap from

    require([
        'app',
        'bootstrap'
    ], function(App){
        App.initialize();
    });

Comment: Didn't help. Okay, my fault bootstrap is not loading at all, I've just mistook it for another file. What's more, all my modules are loading at the beginning..